# 1,000,000 файлов в одной директории

Tags: файлы, linux

Нужно захостить очень много картинок, больше миллиона.

Есть ли разница если сохранять их всех в одной папке:
/pictures/1.jpg,/pictures/2.jpg,...,/pictures/1000000.jpg

Или раздельно:
/pictures/000/000/1.jpg,/pictures/000/000/2.jpg,...,/pictures/100/000/0.jpg

Будут загружаться одинаково быстро или второй вариант быстрее?

OS на сервере - CentOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Многое зависит от файловой системы. Скорее всего, на CentOS выбрана ext3/ext4. Если `dir_index` включен, даже на таких больших количествах файлов время поиска должно быть приемлемо, хотя и неоптимально. Для включения и отключения `dir_index` - tune2fs.

Comment: А как лучше оптимизировать кроме dir_index?

Comment: Можно потестировать и сравнить разные файловые системы: xfs, reiserfs, ext4.

Comment: Я проводил такой эксперимент на ext3 со включённым журналированием и создал 10.000.000 файлов в одной папке. Время поиска файла было очень хорошее. Чиста на глаз казалось, что доступ просиходит мгновенно. Зато обход файлов очень медленно выполнялся. Я помню, что ls и dir выполнялись устрашающе медленно. И ещё, разумеется не стоит даже думать применять команды типа rm -f * и т.п., так как они закончатся неудачей (нехваткой памяти или превышением длины строки).

В конечном итоге, ext* использует дерево для поиска файлов, что достаточно эффективно.